# Why is the move constructor involved here

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization, copy-elision

I have this piece of C++ code:

```
class Args {};

class MyClass {
  public:
  MyClass(Args& a) {}
  MyClass(MyClass &&) = delete;
};

int main() {

  Args a;
  MyClass c1 = MyClass(a);
  MyClass c2 = a;
  MyClass c3(a);

  return 0;
}
```

This does not compile because the construction of objects `c1` and `c2` seem to involve the class's move constructor:

`error: use of deleted function ‘MyClass::MyClass(MyClass&&)’`

It seems as if the compiler wants to create temporary object and then move them to `c1` and `c2`. Why is this happening? Shouldn't all three statements just call the `MyClass(Args& a)` constructor?

On the other hand, if I do create the move constructor the program compiles fine and the move constructor is never called!!!

Comment: copy-elision in action... In C++17, your code should be fine.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See [copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision):

> Under the following circumstances, the compilers are permitted, but not required to omit the copy- and move- (since C++11) construction of class objects even if the copy/move (since C++11) constructor and the destructor have observable side-effects. This is an optimization: **even when it takes place and the copy-/move-constructor is not called, it still must be present and accessible (as if no optimization happened at all), otherwise the program is ill-formed.**

Since C++17:

> They need not be present or accessible, as the language rules ensure that no copy/move operation takes place, even conceptually.

Answer (score 6):

> Why is this happening? Shouldn't all three statements just call the `MyClass(Args& a)` constructor?

For both `MyClass c1 = MyClass(a);` and `MyClass c2 = a;`, temporary `MyClass` will be constructed at first by the constructor `MyClass::MyClass(Args& a)`, then used to copy-initialize the object `c1` and `c2`. The constructed temporaries are rvalues, that means the move-constructor will be selected for the copy initialization.

> On the other hand, if I do create the move constructor the program compiles fine and the move constructor is never called!!!

The reason is [copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision); the copy/move operation is omitted here, results in the fact that `MyClass::MyClass(Args& a)` is used to initialize the object `c1` and `c2` directly.

The rule about copy elision changed since C++17. Note that pre-C++17, copy elision is not guaranteed. And for non-guaranteed copy elision, even when the copy/move operation is omitted the copy/move constructor still needs to be present and accessible.

> This is an optimization: even when it takes place and the copy-/move-constructor is not called, it still must be present and accessible (as if no optimization happened at all), otherwise the program is ill-formed.

After C++17 your code would work fine. For guaranteed copy elision, copy/move constructor is not required to be present or accessible.

> Under the following circumstances, the compilers are required to omit
>   the copy- and move- construction of class objects even if the
>   copy/move constructor and the destructor have observable side-effects.
>   They need not be present or accessible, as the language rules ensure
>   that no copy/move operation takes place, even conceptually:
>
> - In initialization, if the initializer expression is a prvalue and the cv-unqualified version of the source type is the same class as the
>     class of the destination, the initializer expression is used to
>     initialize the destination object:
>
>   ```
>   T x = T(T(T())); // only one call to default constructor of T, to initialize x
>   ```

Answer (score 6):

One major problem is this:

```
MyClass c1 = MyClass(a);
```

This creates a *temporary* object of type `MyClass`, and temporary types are rvalues. It then tries to either *copy-construct* `c1` using the temporary object, or if you have a move-constructor then *move-construct* `c1`.

In C++11 and C++14, there will be no auto-generated copy-constructor for your class (because you have a user-defined (even if deleted) move-constructor), so only the deleted move-constructor is available. Well it would be available if it wasn't deleted, leading to your error.